# How to display ListView Selected item with ViewPager in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager

I want to move the selected quotes (text) from the ListView and display that selected item in another activity with ViewPager + Next and Previous button that show the next and previous element inside the ListView...
(Thanks in advance...)
Here is my Code...

```
lvAmazingQuotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedQuote = amazing_Quotes_List.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(AmazingQuotes_Activity.this, selectedQuote, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

[ScreenShot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmS1K.png)

Comment: You can start a new activity on click and pass the same set of quotes to the new activity and pass the collection to a viewpager adapter. Set the adapter to the view pager. :)

Comment: whlk can u have a code?

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can send your selected item, previous item and next item to another activity

```
lvAmazingQuotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String previousitem= amazing_Quotes_List.get(position-1).toString();   
            String selectedQuote = amazing_Quotes_List.get(position).toString();
             String nextitem= amazing_Quotes_List.get(position+1).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("previous_item", previousitem);
               intent.putExtra("selected_quote", selectedQuote);
               intent.putExtra("next_item", nextitem);
             context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should pass entire list from one activity to another activity in order to achieve OP need.

Comment: Disha Mohite its working with one item, I mean i want to show all the  previous item (Quotes) not one as well as all the next item i mean Quotes...